# How can I select an <option> based on its index in django template

Tags: html, django, forms, django-templates

In django templates, can I select a specific < option > based on its index?

That is, I have a template as with an such:

```
<select>
  <option val='fs-1'>Foo</option>
  <option val='fs-2'>Bar</option>
  ... (Many more options> ...
</select>
```

When I am rendering the template, I know what is the **index** of the item I want selected.

I know I can do this in a way that's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389880/select-option-in-django-template) but I have many < select > tags with lots of options, and this is not an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: are you using django forms? id so, add it to your question. If not, why not? how are you rendering the options: form.field.render() or basic html? I don't see any django... show us what you have tried or we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear when you know what index should be selected or how you determine that from your question, so it's impossible to tell you which way is best. However, in total, there's only three ways to set it:

1. Specify an initial value on the form:

   ```
   form = MyForm(initial={'some_field': 'fs-2'})
   ```
2. The method you linked to, that you don't want to do (cycling through the options and printing `selected="selected"` if the value matches)
3. Use JavaScript (jQuery used for illustration):

   ```
   $('#id_some_field').val('fs-2');
   ```