# django template select option

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have following question : I would like to have a page on which I want to use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) , but list of selection options should come from my database.
I have a table from which I would like to select entries using something like this:
SELECT DISTINCT field FROM table ORDER BY field ASC

This will give a list I want to use in select. In PHP it was quite simple to use it, but in Django (which I learn) I am not sure how it can be achieved.

For some reasons I do not want to use models and ORM, but would like to use direct selects to DB tables which I define by myself in view.

To make this example simple, lets take it from this page :
[Django: Select option in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389880/django-select-option-in-template#8390002)

Lets assume I have DB table  organizations which has two field: ID , Name
I want to select 'name' using the select listed above. After I fetch those data I want them to be used in

```
<select>
<option>org1</option>
<option>org2</option>
.....
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views you have to send organizations data using some query set.
For example in your view you can return:

```
return render(request, template_name, {'organisations': Organisation.objects.all()})
```

The above queryset can be replaced by any other query set. 
Now in template file you can loop through your organisation data like:

```
<select name="somename">
{% for organisation in organisations %}
<option value="{{ orgnisation.id }}"> {{ organisation.name }} </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

The name field in select tag can be used to get the fields when you unpack the post data in your views.

Comment: thanks. it worked. I used return render_to_response('home.html', {'organisations': organizations}) and organization is a list of objects to which I add entries.